# What does this line in the kern.log mean?

Tags: logging

Can anyone explain to me what does this line means and how to check which process and the user tried to create what and why it was denied?

```
audit: type=1400 audit(1618836727.727:855): apparmor="DENIED" operation="create" profile="/usr/sbin/ntpd" pid=1156 comm="ntpd" family="netlink" sock_type="raw" protocol=0 requested_mask="create" denied_mask="create"
```

Answer (score 0):

[`ntpd`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/ntpd) is a daemon for the `Network Time Protocol` which is used to synchronize times in computer systems.

The audit log here just says that `ntpd` tried to create a raw socket connection, which was denied. Since this is a basic system process, I wouldn't bother with it.

And since this is not about programming, this question doesn't belong to stackoverflow. [Serverfault](https://serverfault.com/) and/or [superuser](https://superuser.com/) might be the better choice here.